# Setting up thymeleaf value to anchor tag and null check

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am setting thymeleaf anchr tag href as below to use query param,

```
<a th:href="@{'/page?vars='+${param.q1}+'&varr=' + ${param.q2}}">
```

the above is working fine. But sometimes, I get q1 url param will be null. In that case, I need to set default value.

I have tried like,

```
<a th:href="@{'/page?vars='+${param.q1 != null} ? ${param.q1} : 'default' +'&varr=' + ${param.q2}}">
```

But I am getting error on this page. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using Thymeleaf's [standard URL syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) when generating links (rather than string concatenation).  This expression should work for you:

```
<a th:href="@{/page(vars=${param.q1} ?: 'default',varr=${param.q2})}">
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
<a th:href="@{'/page?vars='+ ${param.q1}?: 'default' +'&varr=' + ${param.q2}}">
```

Source : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-conditionals#1-elvis-operator

Comment: Hi, Not working. getting like 'page?vars=%27+${param.q1}:?%27default%27+%27&va'

Comment: Able to fix by th:if, th:unless. But it adds extra same code.

Comment: Sorry `:?` should be `?:`, amending it in the answer